# How to find references to a Scriptable Object in all scenes

Tags: unity, scriptable-object

I'm going through the code of an open-source Unity project that uses Scriptable Objects as event channels. Currently, when I see a script raise an event (broadcast) through a SO channel, I have no way of finding out which scripts listen on that channel. I'm aware of the "Find references in scene" option, but the listeners are unlikely to all be in the same scene.

Is there a way to find references to a Scriptable Object in ALL scenes, or another way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to find all hardwired(serialized) references to an asset then I find the linked below github repo very helpful. But if your SO events use `UnityEvent` I don't think it  tracks those, only "direct" inspector references. https://github.com/networm/FindReferencesInProject

Comment: @Nikaas that could be the seed of an answer. I'd bet one could modify that code to also look for `UntiyEvent`s and iterate their listeners with `GetPersistentTarget()`...